# azure function via terraform: how to connect to service bus

Tags: azure, function, terraform

I am stuck when trying to deploy an Azure function via Azure DevOps pipelines and Terraform.

Running `terraform apply` works fine and the Service Bus looks good and works. In the Azure portal the function seems to be running, but it complains that it can not find the `ServiceBusConnection`.

I defined it via the following Terraform declaration:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "rg-sb-westeurope"
  location = "westeurope"


}

resource "azurerm_servicebus_namespace" "sb" {
  name                = "ns-sb"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  sku                 = "Standard"

}

resource "azurerm_servicebus_queue" "sbq" {
  name                = "servicebusqueue"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  namespace_name      = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.sb.name

  enable_partitioning = true
}

resource "azurerm_servicebus_namespace_authorization_rule" "sb-ar" {
  name                = "servicebus_auth_rule"
  namespace_name      = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.sb.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  listen = false
  send   = true
  manage = false
}
```

In the function app i declare:

```
resource "azurerm_function_app" "fa" {
  name                       = "function-app"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_app_service_plan.asp.id
 
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.sa.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.sa.primary_access_key
  app_settings = {
      ServiceBusConnection    = azurerm_servicebus_namespace_authorization_rule.sb-ar.name
  }

}
```

This tf. will not work out of the box as i have not copied here the full declaration.
I think I am setting the connection environment vars wrong but have no idea on how to do it correctly.

**EDIT**
With the hint from @Heye I got it working. This is the correct snipped replacing the `name` with `primary_connection_string`.

```
resource "azurerm_function_app" "fa" {
  name                       = "function-app"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_app_service_plan.asp.id
 
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.sa.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.sa.primary_access_key
  app_settings = {
      ServiceBusConnection    = azurerm_servicebus_namespace_authorization_rule.sb-ar.primary_connection_string
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the `ServiceBusConnection` value to the `name` of the authorization rule. However, you probably want to set it to the `primary_connection_string`, as that contains the key along with all the information needed to connect to the Service Bus.